# Working captcha machine learning tool sought

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, captcha

I'm looking for any *working* python3 captcha solver.

My focus lies on a relatively simple six-digit captcha:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Training material are 2000 solved captchas.

I've tried solvers from [dsaveliev](https://github.com/dsaveliev/CaptchaSolver) – which focuses on a very similar captcha, ["Chinese Patrick"](https://github.com/PatrickLib/captcha_recognize/) and [Adam Geitgy](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/how-to-break-a-captcha-system-in-15-minutes-with-machine-learning-dbebb035a710). But they are all throwing various errors and it seems that github user "letarg0" has done the same research like me two weeks earlier.

I'm not determined on single-digit separation. Geitgy's extract_single_letters_from_captchas.py however was not working well for my example.

It's a pity, but I'm not able to write something by myself. Do you know any tool for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use openCV and tesseract OCR

```py
import cv2.cv as cv
import tesseract
gray = cv.LoadImage('captcha.jpeg', cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
cv.Threshold(gray, gray, 231, 255, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY)
api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
api.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
api.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_SINGLE_WORD)
tesseract.SetCvImage(gray,api)
print(api.GetUTF8Text())
```

Source : https://gist.github.com/chroman/5679049